# How to trigger and event and listen to it using non-swing class

Tags: java, events, actionlistener

I'm currently working on a small console application. This application is based on a MVC architecture. My controller add his own ActionListener to the view it manages. My ConsoleView do not extends any Swing or Componenent that allows it to have the method `addActionListener` to it. This is the code of my ConsoleView which has to be run from the command shell and waits for user input.

```
public class ConsoleView implements InterfaceView {
    private Console c = null;

    public ConsoleView() {
        c = System.console();
        if (c == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String input;
        do {
            input = c.readLine();
        } while (!parse(input));
    }

    /**
     * Parse the input and returns true if the input has been successfully
     * parse;
     * 
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean parse(String input) {
        if (input == null || input.equals(""))
            return false;
        input = input.trim();
        int separator = input.indexOf(' ');
        String cmd, arguments;
        if (separator == -1) {
            cmd = input;
            arguments = null;
        } else {
            cmd = input.substring(0, separator);
            arguments = input.substring(separator + 1);
        }
        Commands command;
        try {
            command = Commands.valueOf(cmd);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            command = Commands.help;
        }
        String print = "You used " + cmd + " with arguments :" + arguments;
        switch (command) {
        case startvm:
            break;
        case stopvm:
            break;
        case list:
            break;
        case help:
            break;
        case exit:
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(print);
        return false;
    }

    public static enum Commands {
        stopvm, startvm, list, help, exit
    }
    //cal comes from my controller
    public void addCommandListener(ActionListener cal){
                //This is where i would do this.addActionListener(cal)
    }
}
```

I would also want to be able to trigger these events in the `parse` method so the controller does what it has to do when the listener is noticed that an event has been triggered.

Thanks a lot. If you have an alternative option on how to do it, go ahead I'll listen!

P.S. my boss wants to use that command prompt, thats why no Swing interface !!

Comment: I see some code posted, but none related to anything that you're listening for. This begs the question -- just what is being listened to? What would "trigger" the listener to fire? Where is the code where the listeners are notified of the event? I'm guessing you'd use a PropertyChangeListener if you're listening for the change to a bound class property, but again, given what you've posted, I just can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from implementing the **Observer pattern** in any kind of classes!

You can reuse the *listener* interfaces of Swing if you want or create your own. Then you have to add a register and unregister method to your observable class, that basically adds and removes the *listener* object to a list; and a method that fires the change events (that is, calls the methods on the registered listeners with the relevant parameters).

There is a problem though with your current code, and is that the `parse` method is `static`, you should make it non static so it knows about the list of listeners of the console view.

Comment: We misunderstood what he meant by MVC, it was more of a layer architecture he wanted use to use. Although your answer was very useful in other project with similar requirements. thanks